# .NET 2.0 App.Config connection strings includes unwanted SQLExpress default

Tags: .net, connection-string, app-config

I'm using a `connectionStrings` section within an app.config file in a .NET 2.0 project. The config section contains two connection strings I have defined.

When I retrieve the `ConnectionStringSettingsCollection` it has a count of 3. The 0th entry is a connection to SQLExpress

```
Name: LocalSqlServer,
ConnectionString: data source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true
```

Why is this connection being included even though it's not in my app.config, and how can I get rid of it? This code will be running on desktop machines that I have no access to - so how can I prevent any more local connections from randomly showing up at runtime? I can't see any properties on the connection that indicate it's any different from the two I defined.

Comment: I suspect it has something with the `SqlMembershipProvider` (or maybe an another builtin provider). Have you ever tried to configure one or have one in your web.config?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's defined in machine.config.  To get rid of it, use:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear/>
    <add ... >
</connectionStrings>
```

As a general rule, sections that have `<add>` and `<remove>` elements (e.g. `appSettings`, `connectionStrings` and the provider configuration sections) also have a `<clear>` element, which you can use if you don't want to inherit elements from a higher level web.config or machine.config file.

Comment: great thanks. I love how SO never just solves a problem, I always learn something useful too